# I am unable to mount ADLS Gen2. Please assist

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Code to mount ADLS Gen2:

[image]

Error while mounting ADLS Gen2:

[image]

Comment: Storage Blob Data Contributor role assigned already.

Comment: double check the tenant ID. Also check that AAD is reachable from the cluster nodes - sometimes traffic is blocked by NSG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the error message it clear says - the provided tenant is not found in your subscription. Please make sure the tenant ID is available in your subscription.

**Prerequisites:**

Create and grant permissions to service principal If your selected access method requires a service principal with adequate permissions, and you do not have one, follow these steps:

**Step1:** Create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources. Note the following properties:

- application-id: An ID that uniquely identifies the application.
- directory-id: An ID that uniquely identifies the Azure AD instance.
- service-credential: A string that the application uses to prove its identity.
- storage-account-name: The name of the storage account.
- filesystem-name: The name of the filesystem.

**Step2:** Register the service principal, granting the [correct role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=portal), such as `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role, on the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account.

**Step3:** Azure Data Lake Gen2 mount by passing the values directly.

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "06ecxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxef", #Enter <appId> = Application ID
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "1i_7Q-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXgyC.Szg", #Enter <password> = Client Secret created in AAD
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f98-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx47/oauth2/token", #Enter <tenant> = Tenant ID
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<filesystem>@<StorageName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<Directory>", #Enter <container-name> = filesystem name <storage-account-name> = storage name
mount_point = "/mnt/<mountname>",
extra_configs = configs)
```

[image]

For more details, refer to [Azure Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/).